# CSV generation in client side or backend?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, html, csv

I am using angular js [client side] and node js [for backend].
Which is more efficient and advisable when generating contents as csv,
a. writing the CSV generation, setting of fields [after fetching from backend node js] in client side [using angular or javascript] or
b. getting the CSV file as response from the backend?

Please let me know the pros and cons of both.

Comment: How are you generating the CSV? Where is data coming from? If you're getting data on the server, would make more sense to keep all your logic in one place so it's self contained and more easily testable.

Comment: @timothyclifford pretty much the same questions I wanted to ask... :-)

Comment: Doing this with client-side JS is OK as long as you don't need to support older browsers. Triggering a file download requires a data URL for modern browsers and Flash for everything else. There should be no differences in complexity for generating the CSV itself, but you might get into trouble for large amounts of data if you go the client-side JS way.

Comment: Ideally, your UI should be data driven. Meaning, it should only care about rendering the data (not it's creation). I'd recommend getting a response from the server and then consuming this data on the client.

Comment: @timothyclifford robertKlep I am extracting the data from mysql using nodejs and sending the response back to client side angular. Generation of csv is done using pure javascript.                                                    csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent); So, which you feel is advisable?

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv, so if no old browsers, can I continue with client side CSV generation. Please find the comments above on the detailed steps I follow. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Assumed selected client-side CSV creation.

**Pros :**

- Choosing client-side csv creation; less tiring backend.
- If client has already data it will be useful, if back-end not need to response CSV file.

**Cons :**

- If user has only ancient browser that time, he can't create CSV file.
- Your back-end will tire more.

So technically in all subjects(about performance etc.) developers can dive deeper. These are the basic pros and cons. Also pros and cons can be changed by other requirements or logics.

Answer (score 0):

if the server just fetches data from db I guess it's better to put the `.csv` creation load to the client side; in this way server just sends the raw data to the client browser would do the processing and file creation.